# Stuck: Configure SharePoint 2013 for Apps

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sharepoint-addin

Ran this

```
$account = Get-SPManagedAccount "domain\svc_spspfarm"
```

Then I ran this

```
$appPool = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name SubscriptionServiceAppPool -Account $account
```

The app pool is displayed when I run: `Get-SPSeriviceApplicationPool`.

Running this

```
$appSubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appPoolSubSvc -Name "SubscriptionServiceAppPool" -DatabaseName "SettingsServiceDB"
```

Fails with

> New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication : Cannot validate
>   argument on parameter 'ApplicationPool'. The argument is null. Supply
>   a non-null argument and try the command again. At line:1 char:76
>   + $appSubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appP ...
>   +                                                                            ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-SPSubscript...viceApplication],
>   ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication
>
> $proxySubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy
>   -ServiceApplication $appSubSvc

Answer (score 0):

In your `New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication` command, you referenced the app pool as:

```
-ApplicationPool $appPoolSubSvc
```

But in the code earlier you defined the app pool as:
`$appPool = [...]`

Perhaps you meant:

```
$appSubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appPool -Name "SubscriptionServiceAppPool" -DatabaseName "SettingsServiceDB"
```

Comment: TY for input, can't believe I missed the variable issue! Still not working though. Should I attempt to delete what was created and start over? The App management service is running, I did that through CA. I haven't messed with this stuff in a long time so I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "still not working".

Comment: Did you create the proxy?
$proxySubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $appSubSvc

Only other thing I can think of is permissions - from technet:
Verify that you have the following memberships:
-securityadmin fixed server role on the SQL Server instance.
-db_owner fixed database role on all databases that are to be updated.
-Administrators group on the server on which you are running the Windows PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: After deleting the app pool I closed the PS window, and retried the process. It worked just fine this time. The only thing I did differently this time was to close the PS window after I deleted the App Pool from the previous attempt. Thanks for hanging in there with my poorly articulated half-thoughts!